# How to compare the density of two networks with different network sizes

Tags: python, networkx, network-analysis

Using networkX (python library), I want to compare the density of two networks with different network sizes. For example, network A has 100 nodes and about 20 edges, while network B has 20 nodes and 10 edges.

Density is defined as (number of edges) / (all possible edges within the network). However, comparing the densities of these two networks directly is challenging because even a slight increase in the number of nodes results in a significantly larger denominator.

Is there a way to compare the two networks with different sizes fairly?

I usually analyze my data using Python. If possible, could you please recommend specific libraries or packages, such as scikit-learn?

Comment: Were any of these solutions helpful in resolving your issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

Given a graph G, the key is to calculate the number of edges of a Complete Graph of n nodes. This is a known formula, given by the variable n_possible_edges.

```
n_edges = G.number_of_edges()
n_nodes = G.number_of_nodes()
n_possible_edges = ( n_nodes * ( n_nodes – 1 ) ) / 2 

density =  (n_edges) / (n_possible_edges)
```